# To check whether a character is of English Alphabet (a-zA-Z)

Tags: java, character-encoding, character

The method Character.isLetter(Char c) tells whether the character is a unicode letter. What if I want to check for English letters (a-zA-Z) without regex.

Comment: I tried normal comparison of ascii values but some letters are missed and isLetter() function includes some unnecessary words from other languages

Answer (score 15):

Easy

```
char c = ...;
if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
  //english letter
}
```

Comment: With this kind of comparison some English letters are missed, I don't know why, isLetter() includes those missing letters but some unnecessary letters also come along

Comment: (sigh) Which english letters?